# c# replace number places in list string?

Tags: c#, list, numbers

I'm reading a device and want to send the data to another device using RS232
but when I read the data I get (in HEX)

> 32-36  - 26

while it need to be

> 36-32 - 62

is there a way to find in the list the number part and then change it order

I don't want to use

```
List.Reverse();
```

because all other data is Ok and in the correct order

this is part of the List data :

```
 F7-E5-20-32-36-20-E0-EC-20-F9-F0-E9-E9-E3-F8-5C
```

so I want to find where the Hex is 30-->39 and then replace the order

can I do this ?

Thanks ,

Comment: There's something a bit odd here. You say you want to swap 26 to 62, but that is swapping nibbles within a byte. I can understand some bytes being swapped (because the source is using big-endian and the destination is using little-endian) but the *nibbles* being swapped is somewhat of a red flag... Are you *sure* that you need to swap nibbles like that? (Or is that just a typo, perhaps?)

Comment: yes , because I'm reading from a device that send from right to left  ,and need to send that data to another protocol that read from left to right .  so for 1st device that read hello123 - 2nd device need to read 123olleo (something like this)